# Find all <style> tags inside <head> using Regex in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to find all `<style` tags inside `<head>` using Regex.

I've written the code to find it inside the whole HTML:

```php
$regex = '/(<style.*>(.*)<\/style>)/Usmi';

preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $style_tag) {
  $css = $matches[2][$key];
  // $style_tag will contain full tag and $css will contain its content
}
```

But I only want to find `<style>` tags inside `<head>`.

I tried the following, but it's only capturing the first `<style>` tag:

```php
$regex = '/(<style.*>(.*)<\/style>).*<\/head>/Usmi';

preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $style_tag) {

}
```

Comment: I'll recommend [HTML parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) as a good choice here. Regex may backfire if HTML is dynamic.

Comment: @Mandy8055 I can't use an HTML parser here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use positive look ahead to check if there is a closing `head` tag

```
$content = "<html>
<head>
  <style>something</style>
  <style class='my-class'>other</style>
</head>
<body>
  <style>content</style>
</body>
</html>";
preg_match_all('#(<style.*>(.*)</style>)(?=.*</head>)#Usmi', $content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Gives me

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <style>something</style>
            [1] => <style class='my-class'>other</style>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <style>something</style>
            [1] => <style class='my-class'>other</style>
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => something
            [1] => other
        )

)
```